# HTML dialog backdrop hides part of element inside dialog

Tags: html, css, dialog, modal-dialog

I have the following code where I would like to show a circle in the top left of an HTML `<dialog>`, but the top half of the circle gets hidden by the `::backdrop` of the dialog. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

dialog {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

.dialog-actions {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.dialog.showModal();">open dialog</button>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <form method="dialog">
    <div class="dialog-actions">
      <button>close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's hidden by the overflow of the dialog itself, not the backdrop.  Add `overflow: visible;` to the dialog:

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

dialog {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

.dialog-actions {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.dialog.showModal();">open dialog</button>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <form method="dialog">
    <div class="dialog-actions">
      <button>close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
```